# StatsModel OLS on user defined function

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I am trying to perform OLS on a function that looks like:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to do OLS for this type of function. How can I specify that c is a parameter that needs to be estimated?

```
 X = sm.add_constant(X)
```

i found that this can add a constant term to the predictor but wont work in this case.

Comment: You should look into the statsmodels.formulas.api - http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html

Comment: Also - if you could provide some sample data, it may be easier for us to provide an answer.

Comment: That case is not handled by statsmodels, OLS is only for linear models. It requires non-linear least squares which statsmodels doesn't provide yet. scipy has optimize.curvefit. but the best python package for nonlinear least squares is lmfit https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lmfit/

Comment: Might consider making the lmfit an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can accept lmfit if you post it as an answer. Scipy.optimize also works pretty well I saw. Thanks again.